# Export collage video using metalkit

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, metal, metalkit

How can i export collage video using different resolution videos? I'm trying to achieve like showing first image below, I'm using [AVCustomEdit](https://github.com/Lax/Learn-iOS-Swift-by-Examples/tree/master/AVCustomEdit) demo and have done so far, I created `AVMutableVideoComposition` pass all video trackIDs to `customVideoCompositorClass` and getting all videos `CVPixelBuffer` and than converting in `MTLTexture` than render all textures but problem is my video output size is square(destinationTexture) and videos size is portrait or landscape thats why every video is squeezed also how can i rotate scale position and mask shape every video? also how can i apply cifilters? should i convert every `CVPixelBuffer` to ciImage and ciImage back to `CVPixelBuffer`?

[image: video collage][image: issue image]

```
override func renderPixelBuffer(backgroundTexture: MTLTexture,
                                firstPixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer,
                                secondPixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer,
                                thirdPixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer,
                                fourthPixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer,
                                destinationPixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer) {

    // Create a MTLTexture from the CVPixelBuffer.
    guard let firstTexture = buildTextureForPixelBuffer(firstPixelBuffer) else { return }
    guard let secondTexture = buildTextureForPixelBuffer(secondPixelBuffer) else { return }
    guard let thirdTexture = buildTextureForPixelBuffer(thirdPixelBuffer) else { return }
    guard let fourthTexture = buildTextureForPixelBuffer(fourthPixelBuffer) else { return }
    guard let destinationTexture = buildTextureForPixelBuffer(destinationPixelBuffer) else { return }

    /*
     We must maintain a reference to the pixel buffer until the Metal rendering is complete. This is because the
     'buildTextureForPixelBuffer' function above uses CVMetalTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage to create a
     Metal texture (CVMetalTexture) from the IOSurface that backs the CVPixelBuffer, but
     CVMetalTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage doesn't increment the use count of the IOSurface; only the
     CVPixelBuffer, and the CVMTLTexture own this IOSurface. Therefore we must maintain a reference to either
     the pixel buffer or Metal texture until the Metal rendering is done. The MTLCommandBuffer completion
     handler below is then used to release these references.
     */

    pixelBuffers = RenderPixelBuffers(firstBuffer: firstPixelBuffer,
                                      secondBuffer: secondPixelBuffer,
                                      thirdBuffer: thirdPixelBuffer,
                                      fourthBuffer: fourthPixelBuffer,
                                      destinationBuffer: destinationPixelBuffer)

    // Create a new command buffer for each renderpass to the current drawable.
    let commandBuffer = commandQueue.makeCommandBuffer()!
    commandBuffer.label = "MyCommand"

    /*
     Obtain a drawable texture for this render pass and set up the renderpass
     descriptor for the command encoder to render into.
     */
    let renderPassDescriptor = setupRenderPassDescriptorForTexture(destinationTexture)

    // Create a render command encoder so we can render into something.
    let renderEncoder = commandBuffer.makeRenderCommandEncoder(descriptor: renderPassDescriptor)!
    renderEncoder.label = "MyRenderEncoder"

    guard let renderPipelineState = renderPipelineState else { return }

    modelConstants.modelViewMatrix = matrix_identity_float4x4

    // Render background texture.
    renderTexture(renderEncoder, texture: backgroundTexture, pipelineState: renderPipelineState)

    var translationMatrix = matrix_float4x4(translation: simd_float3(-0.5, 0.5, 0))
    // var rotationMatrix = matrix_float4x4(rotationZ: radians(fromDegrees: -90))
    var scaleMatrix = matrix_float4x4(scaling: 0.25)
    var modelMatrix = translationMatrix * scaleMatrix
    modelConstants.modelViewMatrix = modelMatrix

    // Render first texture.
    renderTexture(renderEncoder, texture: firstTexture, pipelineState: renderPipelineState)

    //        translationMatrix = matrix_float4x4(translation: simd_float3(0.5, -0.5, 0))
    //        rotationMatrix = matrix_float4x4(rotationZ: radians(fromDegrees: -45))
    //        scaleMatrix = matrix_float4x4(scaling: 0.5)
    //        modelMatrix = translationMatrix * scaleMatrix * rotationMatrix
    //        modelConstants.modelViewMatrix = modelMatrix

    //        // Render second texture.
    //        renderTexture(renderEncoder, texture: secondTexture, pipelineState: renderPipelineState)
    //
    //        // Render third texture.
    //        renderTexture(renderEncoder, texture: thirdTexture, pipelineState: renderPipelineState)
    //
    //        // Render fourth texture.
    //        renderTexture(renderEncoder, texture: fourthTexture, pipelineState: renderPipelineState)

    // We're done encoding commands.
    renderEncoder.endEncoding()

    // Use the command buffer completion block to release the reference to the pixel buffers.
    commandBuffer.addCompletedHandler({ _ in
        self.pixelBuffers = nil // Release the reference to the pixel buffers.
    })

    // Finalize rendering here & push the command buffer to the GPU.
    commandBuffer.commit()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use a library called MetalPetal. It is an image processing framework based on Metal.You have to convert the CVPixelBuffer in to MetalImage that is MTIImage. and then you can do anything in the image like there are premade filters and you can apply to it or you can use even CIFilter or your custom filters and you can transform , rotate , crop every frame so that collage frames are accurate . then you have to convert the MTIimage to cvpixelbuffer again . Here you can also CIImage but it will be slow i guess. And you are getting box images maybe for the render size . Please see the render size .

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the [Harbeth](https://github.com/yangKJ/Harbeth) library, which is a Metal-based image processing framework. You can directly add filters to CVPixelBuffer and finally export the video.